# Record and Repeat actions in windows application

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access

I have a third party windows application call it ex. app-DMX doing some analytics using basic actions within the app-DMX like open the software run a Report export the results to excel or PDF

Now I want to simulate the same actions using a macro or some code within MS access ,Is there a way to record the actions of my app-DMX and run it using MS Access?

Comment: Does your application have a help/support forum? YOu might ask if they have a macro recorder (unlikely) or if they provide an API (more likely, but not a certainty) through which you would be able to script a solution for your needs.

Comment: If the application does not support it directly or have an API to allow direct interaction you could explore a "dirty" option using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Access shell function in conjunction with some command line scripts of application